# Asus laptop, keyboard backlight not working

Tags: keyboard, asus-laptop, backlight

I have a N56JR Asus laptop and I upgraded it from win 8.1 to win 10 (using the automatic procedure, not a clean install) keyboard backlight doesn't work anymore. I tried uninstalling the ATK package but didn't solve the problem. All other combinations of fn+key work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a driver issue, reflecting the early state of software on win 10. I would wait, and search for a driver.